# Managing C# snippets

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio, when I right-click I've the option to Insert Snippet.
Are those snippets static or I can add my own snippets? How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own.

There is a whole section on snippets on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392.aspx), you may want to start by reading all the articles in the [Creating Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165393.aspx) page.

Answer (score 1):

menu `Tools -> Code Snippets Manager` should help

Answer (score 1):

This is also [a very nice tool to write them](http://snippetdesigner.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It seems very useful. I've installed-it and I'll try to learn to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A direct way of editing and creating snippets is to work with the *.snippet files in the snippets folder.

On Windows 7 this directory would be:

"C:\Users\your_user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Code Snippets"

You could create a snippet for C# and place it in this directory:

"C:\Users\your_user\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets"